# How to check username and password from database using JDBC in spring MVC?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbc

DAO code

```
public List<UserBeans> authenticateUser(UserBeans userBean) 
    {
        List<UserBeans> userlist =new ArrayList<UserBeans>();
        UserBeans user = new UserBeans();
        //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        java.sql.Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e1) 
        {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select loginid, studentid, email from login " +
                " where email = "+userBean.getemail()+" and password = "+userBean.getpassword());
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            user.setloginid(rs.getInt("loginid"));
            user.setstudentid(rs.getInt("studentid"));
            user.setemail(rs.getString("email"));
            userlist.add(user);
        }
        rs.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        return userlist;        
    }
```

controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doLoginn(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserBeans userBean,BindingResult result, HttpSession session)
    {
        ModelAndView view = null;
        List<UserBeans> bean=new ArrayList<UserBeans>();
         bean=eventlogins.authenticateUser(userBean);
         if(!result.hasFieldErrors())
         {
        if(bean!=null && userBean.getemail()!=null && userBean.getpassword()!=null) 
        {   
            session.setAttribute("bean",bean);
            System.out.println("username and password are correct");
            view =new ModelAndView("studentdashboard"); 
        } 
        else
        {
            view=new ModelAndView("login");
            system.out.println("username and password are wrong");
        }
         }
        return view;
    }
```

how to check whether email and password are correct or not. Actually, DAO returns the list to a controller and then how to match the email and password in the controller code. If email and password are correct, it goes for student dashboard otherwise keeps in login page only.

Comment: You're doing lots of things.. Make it simpler by querying into database using email and password and fetch the data. if data loaded then user is valid else wrong credentials. And you've to return single user to controller callback. `And yes there must be only 1 user with that details, if not then you've to do something at db level also`.

Comment: Sir, how to fetch and retrieve data in the single query. retrieving data to be  stored in a session that's why I put the code like this

Comment: You can find many tutorials and articles and do not store data in session.